# Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ]

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, metamask, bsc

I am writing a contract to addReviewProduct however I cannot getReviewProduct and get the error Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ]

SmartContract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ReviewContract {
    uint256 public reviewCount;
    mapping(uint256 => Review) public reviews;

    event ReviewAdded(
        uint256 indexed reviewId,
        address indexed reviewer,
        uint256 indexed productId,
        uint256 rating,
        string content
    );

    struct Review {
        address reviewer;
        uint256 productId;
        uint256 rating;
        string content;
    }

    function addReview(
        uint256 _productId,
        uint256 _rating,
        string memory _content
    ) external {
        require(bytes(_content).length > 0, "Review content cannot be empty");
        require(_rating >= 1 && _rating <= 5, "Rating must be between 1 and 5");

        reviewCount++;
        reviews[reviewCount] = Review(
            msg.sender,
            _productId,
            _rating,
            _content
        );

        emit ReviewAdded(
            reviewCount,
            msg.sender,
            _productId,
            _rating,
            _content
        );
    }

    function getReviewsByProductId(
        uint256 _productId
    ) external view returns (Review[] memory) {
        uint256 count = 0;
        // Đếm số lượng đánh giá thuộc về sản phẩm
        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= reviewCount; i++) {
            if (reviews[i].productId == _productId) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        // Tạo mảng để lưu trữ đánh giá thuộc về sản phẩm
        Review[] memory productReviews = new Review[](count);
        uint256 index = 0;

        // Lặp lại và lưu trữ đánh giá thuộc về sản phẩm vào mảng
        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= reviewCount; i++) {
            if (reviews[i].productId == _productId) {
                productReviews[index] = reviews[i];
                index++;
            }
        }

        return productReviews;
    }
}
```

ABI :

```
"abi": [
    {
      "anonymous": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "indexed": true,
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "reviewId",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "indexed": true,
          "internalType": "address",
          "name": "reviewer",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "indexed": true,
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "productId",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "rating",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "content",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "ReviewAdded",
      "type": "event"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "_productId",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "_rating",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "_content",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "addReview",
      "outputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "_productId",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "getReviewsByProductId",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "components": [
            {
              "internalType": "address",
              "name": "reviewer",
              "type": "address"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "uint256",
              "name": "productId",
              "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "uint256",
              "name": "rating",
              "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "string",
              "name": "content",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "internalType": "struct ReviewContract.Review[]",
          "name": "",
          "type": "tuple[]"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "reviewCount",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "reviews",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "address",
          "name": "reviewer",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "productId",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "rating",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "content",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    }
  ],
```

Component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import Web3Modal from "web3modal";
import { Address, ABI } from "./constants";

const ReviewComponent = () => {
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const id = 7;

  // const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/');
  // const contract = new ethers.Contract(Address, ABI, provider);

  const handleAddReview = async () => {
    try {
      const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
      const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();

      const contract = new ethers.Contract(Address, ABI, signer);

      // Gọi hàm addReview trong smart contract để thêm đánh giá mới
      // const test = await contract.addReview(id, rating, content); // 1 là id sản phẩm, thay đổi tùy thuộc vào yêu cầu của smart contract
      // console.log(test);
      const transaction = await contract.addReview(id, rating, content);

      console.log("Transaction Hash:", transaction.hash);

      // Lấy receipt để kiểm tra trạng thái của giao dịch
      const receipt = await transaction.wait();
      console.log("Transaction Receipt:", receipt);
      const status = receipt.status;

      if (status === 1) {
        console.log("Review added successfully!");

        const event = receipt.events.find((e) => e.event === "ReviewAdded");

        if (event) {
          const { reviewId, reviewer, productId, rating, content } = event.args;
          console.log("Review Details:", {
            reviewId,
            reviewer,
            productId,
            rating,
            content,
          });

          // Hiển thị đánh giá mới thêm vào
          setReviews([...reviews, { reviewId, reviewer, productId, rating, content }]);
        }
      } else {
        console.error("Review addition failed. Status: ", status);
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding review:", error.message);
    }
  };


  const fetchReviews = async () => {
    try {
      const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
      const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(Address, ABI, provider);

      // Gọi hàm getProductReviews trong smart contract để lấy danh sách đánh giá theo ID sản phẩm
      const productReviewsIndexes = await contract.getReviewsByProductId(7, { gasLimit: 300000 });
      console.log(productReviewsIndexes);
      // Lặp qua chỉ số đánh giá và gọi hàm getReview để lấy thông tin chi tiết



    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error getting product reviews:", error.message);
    }
  };

  // ... (các phần khác của component)


  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Product Reviews</h2>
      <div>
        <label>Rating:</label>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="5" value={rating} onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Review:</label>
        <textarea value={content} onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleAddReview}>Add Review</button><br />
      <button onClick={fetchReviews}>Get Review</button>
      <div>
        {reviews?.map((review, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>Rating: {review.rating}</p>
            <p>Content: {review.content}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReviewComponent;
```

Config :

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    bsc: {  // Đặt tên mạng là bscTestnet hoặc bất kỳ tên nào bạn muốn
      url: "https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/",  // URL của BSC testnet
      accounts: [privateKey],
    },
  },
  solidity: "0.8.19",
};
```

i am deploying on bsc testnet

Please show me where I'm wrong and help me write the getReview function

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).